# C++:: Pointers - Casting from Base class to Derived

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, casting

I saw a piece of code that looked something like this:

```
class A
{
    int foo;
};
class B : public A
{
    int moo;
};
int main()
{
    A *a = new A;
    B *b = (B *)a;  // <-- Isn't that risky to do?

    b->moo = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

Variable **moo** was never initialized through the B constructor and no memory was allocated for the address of **moo**, therefore there are possibilities that, by modifying **moo**, we would be accessing allocated memory responsible for something else in the program. I'm not very good with all these terms used in software development, but I believe this is called Undefined Behaviour?

Please correct and enlightenment me if I'm completely wrong here and also please let me know whether this is safe to do or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code leads to *undefined behavior*, and there's no saying what might happen.

Comment: @Alexander That's why you should downcast with `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: ...so "yes", it's wrong. Btw., you're missing a delete for the new, which is wrong too.

Comment: I think "risky" is an understatement.

Comment: @LogicStuff It would return a NULL pointer, wouldn't it? _deviantfan True. Thanks for pointing out. _zenith Right. Well, shouldn't one of you respond as an answer so that we can close this Question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons C++ introduced new casts is that C-style cast is unsafe in the context of C++. In C++ you should use the appropriate cast and (almost?) never the C-style cast.

In this case no cast would help as it is Undefined Behavior as you have noticed.